# Formatting scraped data Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from this URL [https://www.spoonflower.com/en/shop?on=fabric design](https://www.spoonflower.com/en/shop?on=fabric) names, creator names, fabric types, prices as per fabric type
The good thing is they have public API endpoints which make the data extraction simple
But the problem is they have different URLs for design names and for pricing
i.e to collect names of design and the creator name I have to ping this URL https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en

And for pricing per fabric type requesting this endpoint

https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id=6444170&page_locale=en

I am getting correct data but the problem I stumbled across some formatting issues.

What I am looking for is something like this.
[image: expected_output_result]
Each design with its fabric type alongside its prices in a single row. Instead, I am getting this kind of output
[image: my_output_result]

It would be great if anyone here can guide me through this like how to get the expected_output_result I am looking for.

Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv


cookies = {
    'b': '1.2qu49mazdxsj0.40fc8b88.quqq3d.9q7z',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Spoonflower-Window-UUID': 'a9bc37a2-9eb2-4a1e-8ea1-fcee89347364',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.spoonflower.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.spoonflower.com/',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'If-None-Match': 'W/95d6572c326b81ce98c7ae27ac449d42',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
fabric = []
for fab in fabrics:
    fabric.append(("_".join(fab.upper().split())))


#https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en
#https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id=6444170&page_locale=en

item_endpoint = 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en'
item_response = requests.get(item_endpoint).json()



#item_data = items_json['page_results'][0]
scraped_items = []
for item in item_response['page_results']:
    for fab_type in fabric:
        details_endpoint = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_' + fab_type + '?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+ str(item['designId']) + '&page_locale=en'
        details_endpoint_response = requests.get(details_endpoint, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()
        designName = item['name'],
        screeName = item['user']['screenName']
        fabric_name = details_endpoint_response['data']['fabric_code']
        try:
            test_swatch_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
        except:
            test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            fat_quarter_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
        except:
            fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
        except:
            meter = 'N/A'
        scraped_items.append({
            'designName': designName,
            'screenName': screeName,
            'fabric_name': fabric_name,
            'test_swatch_meter': test_swatch_meter,
            'fat_quarter_meter': fat_quarter_meter,
            'meter': meter
        })
        print(designName, screeName, fabric_name, test_swatch_meter,fat_quarter_meter, meter)

print(json.dumps(scraped_items, indent=2))
        #print(type(details_endpoint))

#print(type(items_json['page_results'][0]))
with open('scraped_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=scraped_items[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in scraped_items:
        writer.writerow(row)


#print(fabric)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is just reconfigure how you construct the output. Instead of a list, use a dictionary where `designName`, `screenName`, followed by the values. One thing to keep in mind is dictionaries don't allow duplicate keys, so had to number the column names, however you can remove those later if you'd like.

See if this gets what you are wanting:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import csv
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


cookies = {
    'b': '1.2qu49mazdxsj0.40fc8b88.quqq3d.9q7z',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Spoonflower-Window-UUID': 'a9bc37a2-9eb2-4a1e-8ea1-fcee89347364',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Origin': 'https://www.spoonflower.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.spoonflower.com/',
    'Sec-GPC': '1',
    'If-None-Match': 'W/95d6572c326b81ce98c7ae27ac449d42',
    'TE': 'Trailers',
}

res = requests.get('https://www.spoonflower.com/spoonflower_fabrics')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
fabrics = [fabric.find('h2').text.strip() for fabric in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product_detail medium_text'})]
fabric = []
for fab in fabrics:
    fabric.append(("_".join(fab.upper().split())))


#https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en
#https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_PETAL_SIGNATURE_COTTON?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id=6444170&page_locale=en

item_endpoint = 'https://pythias.spoonflower.com/search/v1/designs?lang=en&page_offset=0&sort=bestSelling&product=Fabric&forSale=true&showMatureContent=false&page_locale=en'
item_response = requests.get(item_endpoint).json()



#item_data = items_json['page_results'][0]
items_dict = OrderedDict()
for item in item_response['page_results']:
    for fab_type in fabric:
        details_endpoint = 'https://api-gateway.spoonflower.com/alpenrose/pricing/fabrics/FABRIC_' + fab_type + '?quantity=1&shipping_country=PK&currency=EUR&measurement_system=METRIC&design_id='+ str(item['designId']) + '&page_locale=en'
        details_endpoint_response = requests.get(details_endpoint, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()
        designName = item['name']
        screenName = item['user']['screenName']
        fabric_name = details_endpoint_response['data']['fabric_code']
        try:
            test_swatch_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['TEST_SWATCH_METER']['price']
        except:
            test_swatch_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            fat_quarter_meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['FAT_QUARTER_METER']['price']
        except:
            fat_quarter_meter = 'N/A'
        try:
            meter = details_endpoint_response['data']['pricing']['METER']['price']
        except:
            meter = 'N/A'
        
        if (designName, screenName) not in items_dict.keys():
            items_dict[(designName, screenName)] = {}

        itemCount = len(items_dict[(designName, screenName)].values()) / 4
        items_dict[(designName, screenName)].update({'fabric_name_%02d' %itemCount: fabric_name,
        'test_swatch_meter_%02d' %itemCount: test_swatch_meter,
        'fat_quarter_meter_%02d' %itemCount: fat_quarter_meter,
        'meter_%02d' %itemCount: meter})
            
        

        print(designName, screenName, fabric_name, test_swatch_meter,fat_quarter_meter, meter)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(items_dict, orient='index').reset_index(drop=False)
df = df.rename(columns={'level_0':'designName','level_1':'screenName'})
df.to_csv('scraped_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: How can I implement this OrderedDict if I have lists of `designName`, `screenName` and list of tuples of `test_swatch_meter`, `fat_quarter_meter` and `meter`?